# Проблемы с QjackCtl (не видит входа микрофона)

Tags: аудио, ubuntu

Хотел подключить гитару, протестировать процессоры гитарные, но столкнулся с такой проблемой - QjackCtl мне говорит, что мол не вижу что запускать, нет подключенного оборудования...

В настройках полазил с бубном, в итоге поменял драйвер на - dummy  приложение запустилось, но звука так я из него и не выжал  :-[

п.с. бубен: ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

Драйвер менять не стоило - просто JACK пытался запуститься в real-моде... Надо было снять галку с этого режима в настройках, настроить Pulseaudio (указать устройство вывода и режим - с усилителем, без него, устройство ввода и сам ввод...) и только после этого запускать QjackCtl. В его настройках выбрать входы и выходы (они должны там появитсься) просто девайсами, выйти из настроек, кликнуть на соединения и запустить свой Guitarix, Rakarrack и т.д., и затем протянуть связи от появившихся модулей... У меня всё это запускалось и без этого, просто запускал Guitarix, а потом правил связи в QjackCtl... Но в настройках регулятора громкости сначала делал всё, что описал выше...

Comment: Ещё обратите внимание на то что в "Регуляторе громкости" в настройках перепутаны местами вкладки "Входы" и "Выходы"...